# With the cross-product of a 3-dimensional space, how do you find the scalar product with a specific solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, cross-product

In R^3 x R^3 x R^3 , how do I show that for all a, b,c element of R^3 the scalar product of 1) and 2) equations result in the specific end result given?

1. <a, a x b>= 0
2. a x (bxc) = b <a,c> - c<a,b>

Is it right to...

1. Find the cross product of a and b =c
2. Find cross product of a and c
   and then a little clueless on how I would get to the end end line. Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: 1) is clear if you know that the cross product of two vectors is perpendicular to them and the scalar product of two perpendicular vectors is $0$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial.